# Selecting Employee information where IsManager column refers two tables (either condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `Employee` table with `EmployeeId` and `ReportsToEmployeeId` columns, which defines if and how the employee reports to another employee.

```
EmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId     IsManager
----------------------------------------------
2           1                       1
3           2                       0
4           2                       0
5           2                       0
6           2                       0
7           2                       0
8           2                       0
```

I also have another table `AssistantManager`. This table contains two columns `AssistantManagerEmployeeId` and `ReportsToEmployeeId`.

```
AssistantManagerEmployeeId, ReportsToEmployeeId
-----------------------------------------------
3                           1
6                           1
```

I am selecting employees from `Employee` table which includes a column `IsManager`. The `IsManager` column needs to be 1 if the `Employee` table contains 1, or the employee is in `AssistantManager` table. To get that list, I am writing below query -

```
SELECT
    E.EmployeeId,
    E.ReportsToEmployeeId,
    IsManager = (CASE 
                    WHEN E.IsManager = 1 
                        THEN E.IsManager 
                    ELSE 
                        (CASE 
                            WHEN AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId IS NULL
                               THEN 0 
                               ELSE 1 
                         END)
                 END)
FROM 
    Employee E
LEFT JOIN 
    AM ON AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
WHERE 
    E.EmployeeId = 4 -- This result 4, 2, 0
```

Can you please let me know a query that is more efficient - without using two case statements?

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, assuming your sql returns correct result..hence I am just modifying `case-when-then` block :

```
SELECT
    E.EmployeeId,
    E.ReportsToEmployeeId,
    CASE
    WHEN E.IsManager = 1 OR
         AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
    END AS IsManager 

FROM 
    Employee E
LEFT JOIN 
    AM ON AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
WHERE 
    E.EmployeeId = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two cases in one as next:-

```
IsManager = (CASE 
                WHEN E.IsManager = 1 or AM.AssistantManagerEmployeeId IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
            END)
```